# How to get application "namespace" in Swift implicitly?

Tags: swift, xcode

**Short version:**

Assuming I have an app called `MyApp`. In some situation I have a duplicate class name so that one is `MyClass` where the other is `MyApp.MyClass`. How can I call `MyApp.MyClass` having `MyApp` constant (do not need to change the code if I change the app name).

**Why and what happened (long version):**

So assume we are in this `MyApp` application having following code (the real one is way way longer and used allover the app):

```
class MyClass {

}

class SomeOtherClass {
    class MyClass {
    }

    func findMyClass(fromMyClass: MyApp.MyClass) -> MyClass {
        ...
    }
}
```

Because there are two classes called `MyClass` in inner scope we need to call `MyApp.MyClass` to get the outer one which is all good. 
But it seems a bit silly when `MyApp` changes which is my case.

**Why did it change?** I actually added a new target by duplicating the original one because I wanted to have some extra and some different settings (pretty standard procedure). So I renamed the new one to have `MyApp-dev` where I then got an error `Use of undeclared type 'MyApp'`.

So is there a keyword that can replace `MyApp`?

My current solution is to define a `typealias` on file scope that is then used inside the class to replace `MyApp`. The problem is that the method is not private so the `typealias` may not be private either which means I just have an extra name defined globally in the project.

**EDIT:**

Also there is a setting in Xcode build settings called `Product Module Name` which may be overridden to explicit naming which fixes the issue. Still this not really a good general solution; I can see cases where you might reuse the same code in multiple modules (creating libraries) which has the same issue. This would still meant that code would need to be fixed for each of these modules.

Comment: There's no way to refer to "current module", no. You have to use its name.